# rails rack attack throttle requests to N requests per hour per authenticated user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, blocking, throttling, rackattack

I am using rails **5.2.4** and ruby **2.5.8**

api authentication with **gem knock** for jwt token with devise model

using `gem rack-attack` for this feature

I want to implement two cases followed,

> **I want to throttle request if user is authenticated** 
> If user is
> authenticated with given access token in header to get resource
> object in api then he can allow 60 authenticated request per hour.

```
Rack::Attack.throttle('login', limit: 60, period: 60.minute) do |req|
  begin
    # req.params for JSON is not yet available at this step
    JSON.parse(req.body.string)['email'] if req.path == '/api/v1/user_token' && req.post?
  rescue JSON::ParserError => e
  end
end
```

> **I want to Allow2Ban(lock) request if user is unauthenticated** If user
> is unauthenticated with given access token in header to get resource
> object in api then lock out any source IP that generates more than 10
> unauthenticated requests within a 5 minute span for 2 hours.

```
Rack::Attack.blocklist('basic auth crackers') do |req|
  Rack::Attack::Allow2Ban.filter(req.ip, :maxretry => 10, :findtime => 5.minute, :bantime => 2.hour) do
    # Return true if the authorization header is incorrect
    auth = Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(req.env)
    auth.credentials != [my_username, my_password]
  end
end
```

**First case:**
In the throttle code the request is throttle even if user pass wrong credentials and not getting JWT access token. I want to throttle request if authenticated user hits for more than 60 request per hour.
api details:

```
POST localhost:3000/api/v1/user_token
request raw JSON body(correct credentials): {"auth": {"email": "sean@public.com", "password": "password"}}
```

**Second case:**
In the allow2block code the request user is passing access token in header to call `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users`. I am not getting how to check if the user has wrong access token or he is unauthenticated.

I am using this middleware for first time and any help appreciated thanks in advance.